# Efficient way to replace all column values using list of strings R

Tags: r, regex, string, list

I have a dataframe called `car` and am trying to replace certain values in the column called `make` which contains a number of unique car makes. I am trying to replace any value contained my a list of characters called `car_list` with the value `low_frequency`. However I only want whole string replacements, not partial which I have done by using boundaries.

The 'make' column of 'car' looks as such:

```
 make
 "LANDROVER"
 "VOLKSWAGEN"
 "VAUXHALL"
 "MG-MOTOR UK"
 "ROVER"
 "BWM"
```

'car_list` looks as such:

```
"MG-MOTOR UK"
"ROVER"
"ROBIN"
```

I which to replace all values in `make` that are contained in `car_list` with the new value `low_frequency`. The output should look as such:

```
 make
 "LANDROVER"
 "VOLKSWAGEN"
 "VAUXHALL"
 "low_frequency"
 "low_frequency"
 "BWM"
```

My attempt was using `gsub` and a for loop as I am used to python but I know this is bad practice in R and the solution crashes:

```
for (string in car_list){
  car['make'] <- gsub(paste('\\b', string, '\\b', sep = ''), 'low_frequency', car['make'])}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `replace`.

```
replace(car$make, car$make %in% car_list, "low_frequency")
# [1] "LANDROVER"     "VOLKSWAGEN"    "VAUXHALL"      "low_frequency" "low_frequency" "BWM"
```

or with `""`

```
replace(car[["make"]], car[["make"]] %in% car_list, "low_frequency")
```

which would look in a function something like:

```
FUN <- function(x) replace(car[[x]], car[[x]] %in% car_list, "low_frequency")
FUN("make")
# [1] "LANDROVER"     "VOLKSWAGEN"    "VAUXHALL"      "low_frequency" "low_frequency" "BWM"
```

---

*Data:*

```
car <- structure(list(make = c("LANDROVER", "VOLKSWAGEN", "VAUXHALL", 
"MG-MOTOR UK", "ROVER", "BWM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

car_list <- list("MG-MOTOR UK", "ROVER", "ROBIN")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the format `car['make']` ?

Comment: The reason for this is that if I put this in a function and replace `make` with `column` to make the solution reproducible for other columns, I cannot enter `car$column`

Comment: @geds133 I understand, you'll need double `[[` though, see edit.